# No updated data in detail DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

There are 2 DataGrid on the form linked to CollectionViewSource. When update a ObservableCollection Parts are updated only dataGridMaster. If I click on it, then the data appears in dataGridDetail1. Question. How to make that data is updated without mouse clicks?

XAML:

```html
    <Window.Resources>
        <CollectionViewSource x:Key="vsmaster"  Source="{Binding Parts}"/>
        <CollectionViewSource x:Key="vsdetail1" Source="{Binding PARTIES_V1, Source={StaticResource vsmaster}}" />
    </Window.Resources>

    <DataGrid x:Name="dataGridMaster" AutoGenerateColumns="False" EnableRowVirtualization="True" 
      ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource vsmaster}}"  Margin="0,10,346,384" 
      RowDetailsVisibilityMode="VisibleWhenSelected">
    <DataGrid x:Name="dataGridDetail1" IsReadOnly="True" SelectionMode="Single" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
      EnableRowVirtualization="True" 
              ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource vsdetail1}}" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" 
              Margin="0,149,346,215" RowDetailsVisibilityMode="VisibleWhenSelected">
      
public class Part
    public Part(int id, string pnumber, string owner, int? priceid,
        List<PARTIES_V1> lparties) 
    {
        ID = id;
        PART_NUMBER = pnumber;
        OWNER = owner;
        PRICE_ID = priceid;
        PARTIES_V1 = lparties;
    }
    public int ID { get; set; }

    public string PART_NUMBER { get; set; }

    public string OWNER { get; set; }

    public int? PRICE_ID { get; set; }

    public List<PARTIES_V1> PARTIES_V1 { get; set; }
```

My ViewModel

```html
class MainWindowViewModel : BaseViewModel
    {
        public string Npart {get; set;} 
        private ObservableCollection<PartsView> _parts;
        public ObservableCollection<PartsView> Parts
        {
            get
            {
                return _parts;
            }
            set 
            {
                _parts = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Parts");
            }
        }
        public MainWindowViewModel()
        {
            _parts = PartsRepository.GetStartData();
        }

        RelayCommand _findPartCommand;
        public ICommand FindPart
        {
            get
            {
                if ( _findPartCommand == null)
                     _findPartCommand = new RelayCommand(ExecuteFindPartCommand, CanExecuteFindPartCommand);
                return _findPartCommand;
            }
        }

        public void ExecuteFindPartCommand(object parameter)
        {
            _parts = PartsRepository.GetPart(Npart);
        }

        public bool CanExecuteFindPartCommand(object parameter)
        {
            return true;
        }
```

Comment: I don't see the MVVM implementation as such .can you add some code - Assigning datacontext, INOtifyPropertyChanged,etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you didn't post complete code. So, I created one myself to see the problem.

After doing your changes, you have to Refresh your collection view using Refresh().

```
    ((ListCollectionView)dataGridMaster.ItemsSource).Refresh();
```

** old answer without VM support **

My sample app code :

```
<Window x:Class="WpfResources._32691328.Win32691328"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="Win32691328" Height="661.015" Width="506.391">
    <Window.Resources>
        <CollectionViewSource x:Key="vsmaster"  Source="{Binding Parts}"/>
        <CollectionViewSource x:Key="vsdetail1" Source="{Binding PARTIES_V1, Source={StaticResource vsmaster}}" />
    </Window.Resources>
    <StackPanel>
        <DataGrid x:Name="dataGridMaster" AutoGenerateColumns="True" EnableRowVirtualization="True" 
      ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource vsmaster}}"   
      RowDetailsVisibilityMode="VisibleWhenSelected"></DataGrid>
        <Button Content="UpdatePart" Click="Button_Click"/>
        <DataGrid x:Name="dataGridDetail1" Margin="0 10 0 0" IsReadOnly="True" SelectionMode="Single" AutoGenerateColumns="True" 
            EnableRowVirtualization="True" 
            ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource vsdetail1}}" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" 
            RowDetailsVisibilityMode="VisibleWhenSelected"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>

using System;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace WpfResources._32691328
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for Win32691328.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class Win32691328 : Window
    {
        public Win32691328()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            this.DataContext = new DataStore();
        }

        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            List<PARTIES_V1> p = new List<PARTIES_V1>();
            p.Add(new PARTIES_V1() { ID = -1999 });
            p.Add(new PARTIES_V1() { ID = -1785 });
            p.Add(new PARTIES_V1() { ID = -1123 });

            ObservableCollection<Part> parts = (ObservableCollection<Part>)((ListCollectionView)dataGridMaster.ItemsSource).SourceCollection;
            parts[0].PARTIES_V1 = p;

            ((ListCollectionView)dataGridMaster.ItemsSource).Refresh();
        }
    }
}


using System;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace WpfResources._32691328
{
    public class DataStore
    {
        ObservableCollection<Part> _parts;
        public ObservableCollection<Part> Parts { get { return _parts; } set { _parts = value; } }

        public DataStore() {

            List<PARTIES_V1> p1 = new List<PARTIES_V1>();
            p1.Add(new PARTIES_V1() { ID = 1999 });
            p1.Add(new PARTIES_V1() { ID = 1785 });
            p1.Add(new PARTIES_V1() { ID = 1123 });

            List<PARTIES_V1> p2 = new List<PARTIES_V1>();
            p2.Add(new PARTIES_V1() { ID = 289 });
            p2.Add(new PARTIES_V1() { ID = 2644 });
            p2.Add(new PARTIES_V1() { ID = 2321 });

            List<PARTIES_V1> p3 = new List<PARTIES_V1>();
            p3.Add(new PARTIES_V1() { ID = 3754 });
            p3.Add(new PARTIES_V1() { ID = 37543 });
            p3.Add(new PARTIES_V1() { ID = 31333 });

            _parts = new ObservableCollection<Part>();
            _parts.Add(new Part(1, "123", "1abc", 111, p1));
            _parts.Add(new Part(5, "3453", "2abc", 111, p2));
            _parts.Add(new Part(7, "13433", "3abc", 111, p3));
            _parts.Add(new Part(8, "2223", "4abc", 111, p1));
            _parts.Add(new Part(10, "155553", "5abc", 111, p3));
            _parts.Add(new Part(11, "122223", "6abc", 111, p2));

        }
    }

    public class Part
    {
        public Part(int id, string pnumber, string owner, int? priceid,
            List<PARTIES_V1> lparties)
        {
            ID = id;
            PART_NUMBER = pnumber;
            OWNER = owner;
            PRICE_ID = priceid;
            PARTIES_V1 = lparties;
        }
        public int ID { get; set; }

        public string PART_NUMBER { get; set; }

        public string OWNER { get; set; }

        public int? PRICE_ID { get; set; }

        public List<PARTIES_V1> PARTIES_V1 { get; set; }
    }

    public class PARTIES_V1
    {

        public int ID { get; set; }

    }
}
```

** new answer with VM support **

```
<Window x:Class="WpfResources._32691328.Win32691328"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="Win32691328" Height="661.015" Width="506.391">

  <StackPanel>
    <DataGrid x:Name="dataGridMaster" AutoGenerateColumns="True" EnableRowVirtualization="True"                    
            RowDetailsVisibilityMode="VisibleWhenSelected" />
    <Button Content="UpdatePart" Click="Button_Click"/>
    <DataGrid x:Name="dataGridDetail" Margin="0 10 0 0" IsReadOnly="True" SelectionMode="Single" AutoGenerateColumns="True" 
        EnableRowVirtualization="True" 
         IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" 
        RowDetailsVisibilityMode="VisibleWhenSelected"/>
   </StackPanel>    
</Window>

using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;

namespace WpfResources._32691328
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for Win32691328.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class Win32691328 : Window
    {
        DataStore d;

        public Win32691328()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            d = new DataStore();
            this.DataContext = d;

            // Bind ItemsSource of both Grids

            Binding bi1 = new Binding();
            bi1.Source = d.PartsView;
            bi1.Mode = BindingMode.OneWay;
            BindingOperations.SetBinding(dataGridMaster, DataGrid.ItemsSourceProperty, bi1);

            Binding bi2 = new Binding();
            bi2.Source = d.PartiesDetailView;
            bi2.Mode = BindingMode.OneWay;
            BindingOperations.SetBinding(dataGridDetail, DataGrid.ItemsSourceProperty, bi2);
        }

        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            d.Change();           
        }
    }
}

using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Windows.Data;

namespace WpfResources._32691328
{
    public class DataStore
    {
        ObservableCollection<Part> _parts;
        public ObservableCollection<Part> Parts { get { return _parts; } set { _parts = value; } }

        CollectionViewSource _partsViewMaster;
        public CollectionViewSource PartsView
        {
            get { return _partsViewMaster; }
        }

        CollectionViewSource _partsDetailView;
        public CollectionViewSource PartiesDetailView
        {
            get { return _partsDetailView; }
        }

        public DataStore() {

            _partsViewMaster = new CollectionViewSource();
            _partsDetailView = new CollectionViewSource();          

            List<PARTIES_V1> p1 = new List<PARTIES_V1>();
            p1.Add(new PARTIES_V1() { ID = 1999 });
            p1.Add(new PARTIES_V1() { ID = 1785 });
            p1.Add(new PARTIES_V1() { ID = 1123 });

            List<PARTIES_V1> p2 = new List<PARTIES_V1>();
            p2.Add(new PARTIES_V1() { ID = 289 });
            p2.Add(new PARTIES_V1() { ID = 2644 });
            p2.Add(new PARTIES_V1() { ID = 2321 });

            List<PARTIES_V1> p3 = new List<PARTIES_V1>();
            p3.Add(new PARTIES_V1() { ID = 3754 });
            p3.Add(new PARTIES_V1() { ID = 37543 });
            p3.Add(new PARTIES_V1() { ID = 31333 });

            _parts = new ObservableCollection<Part>();
            _parts.Add(new Part(1, "123", "1abc", 111, p1));
            _parts.Add(new Part(5, "3453", "2abc", 111, p2));
            _parts.Add(new Part(7, "13433", "3abc", 111, p3));
            _parts.Add(new Part(8, "2223", "4abc", 111, p1));
            _parts.Add(new Part(10, "155553", "5abc", 111, p3));
            _parts.Add(new Part(11, "122223", "6abc", 111, p2));


            Binding bc1 = new Binding("Parts");
            bc1.Source = this;
            BindingOperations.SetBinding(_partsViewMaster, CollectionViewSource.SourceProperty, bc1);

            Binding bc2 = new Binding("PARTIES_V1");
            bc2.Source = _partsViewMaster;
            BindingOperations.SetBinding(_partsDetailView, CollectionViewSource.SourceProperty, bc2);
        }

        public void Change()
        {
            // Do some changes

            List<PARTIES_V1> p = new List<PARTIES_V1>();
            p.Add(new PARTIES_V1() { ID = -1999 });
            p.Add(new PARTIES_V1() { ID = -1785 });
            p.Add(new PARTIES_V1() { ID = -1123 });

            _parts[0].PARTIES_V1 = p;

            // recreate view
            _partsViewMaster.View.Refresh();
        }
    }

    public class Part
    {
        public Part(int id, string pnumber, string owner, int? priceid,
            List<PARTIES_V1> lparties)
        {
            ID = id;
            PART_NUMBER = pnumber;
            OWNER = owner;
            PRICE_ID = priceid;
            PARTIES_V1 = lparties;
        }
        public int ID { get; set; }

        public string PART_NUMBER { get; set; }

        public string OWNER { get; set; }

        public int? PRICE_ID { get; set; }

        List<PARTIES_V1> _parties = new List<PARTIES_V1>();
        public List<PARTIES_V1> PARTIES_V1 { get { return _parties; } set { _parties = value; } }

    }

    public class PARTIES_V1
    {

        public int ID { get; set; }

    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for  answer. How I can do it in MVVM?

Comment: If you feel answer is good, please mark it as an answer. You are using CollectionViewSource as your window resources. These collectionviewsources are not coming from ViewModel. We have used Refresh() method of ListCollectionView which is your ItemsSource. If you are using a ViewModel, then these CollectionViewSources (present in your Window.Resources) will come from your VM. More can be said about this if you post your VM code.

Comment: @user3041373 I have added new answer with ViewModel support. I have used my own code. You can focus on the concept used. And try on your own. Now, CollectionViewSources are no longer present in XAML code, but coming from VM side.